# Strange event using String.length on eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a string which has a value I tested and saw on debug on values and on logcat.

Now I performed this code. method1() returns a string; the string is checked on logcat and debug which has values.

```
String string = method1();

int datalegnth = string.length();
```

Now on logcat and debug value column "dataLegnth" it is not even listed nor does it show a value.

On logcat value screen string = "this is a gigantic string which probably exceeds over 500 characters".
On debug screen string = "this is a gigantic string which probably exceeds over 500 characters".

My approach on seeing data is on logcat is

```
Log.i("dataLegnth:", Integer.toString(dataLegnth));
```

Nothing shows on logcat or on value on debug mode for dataLegnth. I tried project clean as well. There are no errors on logcat.

Has anyone encountered a problem similar to this or does anyone have a solution?

Comment: No its just an example I used on stackoverflow

Comment: To be honest I did this before and I never had a problem. Just now it seems to be giving me this bug.

Comment: But there's no `dataLegnth` variable--this also shouldn't compile.

Comment: I believe dataLegnth should be string.legnth(); since it's just standard declaration of variables.
If I would say int dataLegnth = 0;
then do dataLegnth = string.legnth();
then show on screen it should give me an integer amount

Comment: That should also not compile, since there is no `string.legnth()`. Do you see that you're not typing the word "length" correctly? Typos obfuscate any real problems you may or may not be having, and make it difficult to know what is a real issue, and what is you not being able to see what you type.

Comment: Sorry keep typing incorrectly on stackoverflow doesn't auto correct for me like in eclipse. I will update question again.

Comment: If possible use copy-paste to get the code exact. Your question uses datalegnth and dataLegnth. Could you possibly have an object dataLegnth which is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be miss logic I rewritten my code and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want `dataLength` on your LogCat, just add this somewhere:

```
Log.d(null, "Value of dataLength: " + dataLength);
```

When you execute your program, the LogCat should read "Value of dataLength: (some value)" wherever you implemented the code.
If the LogCat reads "Value of dataLength:" when you execute your program however, dataLength is probably null and something is not right in your code.

Otherwise, I don't understand what you are asking.  Please be more specific.

Comment: I updated the question to have logcat values as well as what is seen on debug value sceen

Comment: My question was dataLegnth is not showing at all in either logcat or the value screen on debug.